# insufficient user rights

Tags: permissions, kubuntu, libreoffice

I am a real newbie. I have Kubuntu 18.04 dual booted with windows 10. They both access files in a separate drive to the OS's. All was working fine for several weeks. Now when in Kubuntu all is fine except when I try to save edited files from any program (including LIbreOffice 6.0.7.3) I get: **"Object not accessible. The object cannot be accessed due to insufficient user rights."** In Windows all is still fine but my objective is to say goodbye to it. I cannot think of anything that could have caused this. I have checked using Windows that it considers all drives healthy following advice in a similar question.

Disk Setup

```
NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID                         MOUNTPOINT   SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
fd0                                                           4K root  disk  brw-rw----
sda                                                       223.6G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda1
│    ntfs   System Reserved
│                 86C6F9ACC6F99C9D                          500M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda2
│    ntfs         F85E3B505E3B0742                        222.3G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda3
     ntfs         1A2843C628439F9D                          837M root  disk  brw-rw----
sdb                                                         3.7T root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdb1
│                                                           128M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdb2
│    ntfs   Data Store
│                 01D20AECC9B1D480             /media/fri   1.8T root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdb3
│    ntfs   System Store
│                 01D20AECCD70D850                        318.7G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdb4
│                                                             1M root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sdb5
     ext4         fadeaf64-7096-4340-a534-05c02c087e07 /    1.6T root  disk  brw-rw----
```

Comment: A Windows update may have reenabled Windows fast-startup.

Comment: Please show us your disks setup : edit your question to add the output of this comand `lsblk -fm -e 7,11,252`

Comment: Thanks @mook765 that has cured the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are modifying a word document from the windows drive that would be a bit tricky.

Windows likes to keep it's grubby fingers in the pie, ESPECIALY if you have fast boot on. I would turn fast startup off,

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

If that's not the case, I would check your systems file permissions, make sure you didn't accidently bork your permissions.

A little script I wrote to help with web server permissions. you would copy it into a text file, save the file as "perm.sh" in the command line run

```
chmod +x perm.sh
```

and then run it

```
./perm.sh

for i in /* ; do
igno=("/dev" "/sys" "/proc" "/tmp" "/mnt" "/media");

subdir=$(find $i -type d);


if [[ $(echo "$i") != $(echo $igno) ]]; then

printf "\n\n$i has the following stats:\n\n" ;
printf "\n_______________________________________\n\n" ;
stat -c "%n  %a %G:%U"  $subdir | tail -15 | head -14;
printf "\n\n______________________________________\n" ;
fi
```

I wouldn't post those results here, but just review them, if something doesn't look right, ask.

I love teaching people about linux if you ever need a hand or just wanna chat about linux, drop me a line!

Comment: Thanks, appreciation and respect to all who helped here. Yes it was just Fast Startup causing the problem.